# How run apk application without installing(native)

Tags: android, c, apk

Is there any way to run an apk without installing? Just like in windows running an exe. Does being a native apk change anything in relation to this?

Comment: There is no way (probably there is, but it requires too many manipulations, root access, etc.). `.exe` in Windows is executable file, while `.apk` in Android is an application package, not executable.

Comment: so apk is like a .rar / zip?

Comment: it **is** a zip archive in fact, just renamed from `.zip` to `.apk`

Comment: so how does this work, the OS extracts the apk and runs?

Comment: it extracts the APK, parses manifest, and runs the `class` code of the activity in the Java virtual machine

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko your answers are good, you should post them with more detail as an answer to this question so it can be valuable to future readers.

Comment: @girlvsdata you are right, will do

Comment: I think I understood thanks a lot ^^

Answer (score 9):

Short answer is:

You can't.

Long answer(TL;DR):

If compared to Windows's `.exe` file, which is *binary, and can be executed*, `.apk` is *not a binary, and can't be executed*. `.apk` in fact is a `zip` archive, just named with `.apk` instead of `.zip`.
For Android `.apk` is an application package, which has the executable code + resources + assets + whatever else it needs. This means that the `.apk` file is not being run itself.

How it works (simplified):
When you start an application on Android, system extracts `.apk` file, opens the `manifest` file, finds a launcher activity you have selected to start, and executes it's `Activity.class` code on the Java VM.

So in fact you can do that having root access by manually extracting APK, starting a virtual machine and running `.class` code in it, but IMHO it is not worth to do.

What you *can* run is most part of `arm` compiled Linux binaries. If they don't require access to the system-owned files, or other data, or you have root access on your device, you can use `arm` binaries. But you still need some APK installed to run them.

---

Note that the answer is simplified for easier understanding, and in fact everything is more complicated with APKs, Java VM, etc.

Answer (score 1):

During apk installation (even via adb), managed by the android Package Manager on the device, various processes are executed such as:

- Determine the appropriate location of the package installation
- Copying a copy of the apk file to a given directory (usually /data/app/)
- Create the application directory and set permissions to store database and shared preference, native library (usually /data/data//)
- Extraction of dex code to the cache directory

There is no way an apk can run on an android device if it's resources and configuration are not on the same device.